# Use gem 'postgres-copy' to import csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv

currently, I want to import above 55,000 records into my database from a CSV file. This is the code that I am using:

```
CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join('db/seeds/locations.csv'), headers: true) do |row|
  val                = Location.find_or_initialize_by(code: row[0])
  val.name           = row[1]
  val.ecc            = row[2] || 'MISSING'
  val.created_by     = User.find_by(name: 'anh')
  val.updated_by     = User.find_by(name: 'anh')
  val.save!
end
```

However, it is too slow and I have just installed the gem 'postgres-copy'. I read the official documentation, and I believe I can use the class method `copy_from` to do the job, but if you read my current code, you can see that I am referring the data to the another table(association), and the documentation doesn't mention anything about association or validation. Therefore, I am wondering if there are any ways to solve it. This is the first time I use this gem. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that gem, but I would be very surprised if it can support multi-table copy since PostgreSQL's COPY works on a single table.  50K rows isn't all that many. You might try wrapping your insertions in transactions to avoid one commit per transaction.  Doubt you want to wrap all 50K in a transaction though, but something like this:

```
User.connection.begin_transaction
i = 0
CSV.foreach(...) do |row|
  ... # your original code here 

  i += 1
  if i % 500 == 0
    User.connection.commit_transaction
    User.connection.begin_transaction  
  end
end
User.connection.commit_transaction
```

This will insert your rows 500 records at a time and you should see a noticeable speed up.  Play around with the value of 500 to find the sweet spot.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I appreciate it. I am going to test it and let you know about the result. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, now I understand that I cannot take advantage of the COPY command in POSTGRESQL since it can't copy multiple tables. Therefore, I switch to the gem activerecord-import. Comparing with the method that Philip Hallstrom mentioned above, using activerecord-import give a faster result, 1m20s vs 1m54s to import above 8000 records.
This is my code after installing the gem activerecord-import. Hopefully, it can help other people.

```
locations = []
columns = [:code, :name, :ecc]
CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join('db/seeds/locations.csv'), headers: true) do |row|
  val                = Location.find_or_initialize_by(code: row[0])
  val.name           = row[1]
  val.ecc            = row[2] || 'MISSING'
  val.created_by     = User.find_by(name: 'anh')
  val.updated_by     = User.find_by(name: 'anh')
  locations << val
end
Location.import columns, locations, validate: false
```